# Error converting json response to custom class

Tags: java, json, spring, glassfish

I'm using GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.2. And I have the following code:

Usuario.java (a custom class where i want to store json response):

```
package masterticket.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Usuario implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int id;
    String nombre;
    String apellidos;
    String tipo;
    String email;
    String password;
    java.sql.Timestamp created;

    public Usuario(){
    }

    public Usuario(String nombre, String apellidos, String tipo, String email, String password){
        this.nombre   = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public java.sql.Timestamp getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(java.sql.Timestamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

}
```

A spring controller:

```
package es.uc3m.tiw;


import es.uc3m.tiw.domains.*;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Controller
public class Usuarios_Controller {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioDAO daousu;

    @RequestMapping("/todosusuarios")
    public @ResponseBody List<Usuario> getEventos(){
        return daousu.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/usuarios/{email}")
    public @ResponseBody Usuario getEventosByIdUsuario(@PathVariable String email){
        return daousu.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/usuarios", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Usuario saveuser(@RequestBody Usuario puser){
        return daousu.save(puser);
    }

}
```

And a servlet where i execute the call to the spring app:

```
...
client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            webResource = client.target("http://localhost:10507/usuarios/"+email+"/");
            System.out.println("http://localhost:10506/usuarios/"+email+"/ poniendo usuario");
            Usuario usu=    webResource.request().accept("application/json").get(Usuario.class);
            System.out.println(usu.getApellidos());
...
```

For some reason im not able to understand im getting this error on the glassfish log and this code wont work:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.isConstrainedObject(JAXBBeanValidator.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.shouldValidate(JAXBBeanValidator.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.validateAndBuildJAXBElement(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:660)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:852)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:786)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:803)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
    at masterticket.controllers.login.doPost(login.java:115)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

API is working good because i tested it using postman and all calls work as expected. In fact im able to retrieve the response into a String but when I try to do the same with the Usuario class provided above, code breaks..

This is an example of the json im trying to parse:

```
[{"id":1,"nombre":"admin1","apellidos":"admin1","tipo":"admin","email":"admin1@correo.es","password":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","created":1510500279000}]
```

Comment: since you are implementing the Serializable interface shouldn't you have to implement the methods pertaining to the Serializable interface given here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html...? just curious

Comment: That shouldnt be neccesary, ill edit the question with the json im trying to parse into an object, all the fields match exactly the class attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be [a bug in `Glassfish`](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/21440) at least there seems to have been one like this in 4.1.1 and I'm not sure if it was patched by 4.1.2

Comment: Thats right!! I executed it under a Payara Server 4.1.1.163 #badassfish (build 215) and it worked. So, yeah, surely that bug wasnt patched on my version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Forget about Glassfish! Use **payara** (https://www.payara.fish/) and make yourself happy!

Comment: Uhm whats the difference between them? I dont understand why same code is working on payara and not in glassfish